# Suggestions to make Outlook mail merge quicker

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, mail-merge, microsoft-publisher

I am using Microsoft Publisher 2007 to create Newsletters and 'Mail Merge' them to Outlook 2007. The newsletters consist mainly of images of size between 200-500KB.

My contact list is around 5000, and it takes me 4-5 hours to complete this whole activity, sending in batches of 1000 each.

Is there a time saving way of doing this, without any bulk mail software?

I have observed the following which may save me some time, but I need help solutions:

1. Outlook saves each mail, which I feel increases the time. **Is there an option in Mail Merge to bypass this action and will that save me some time?**
2. The maximum limit of email addresses in one email is 7 recipients, as laid down by my organization. **Is there a way to create small distribution lists of 7 each, which will lead to 715 DLs, and can mail merge be done on those DLs?**
3. Is there any method to emulate the way in Outlook, when we send email to multiple addresses in one email, to do the same for the mail merge task.

Note: *The time taken to do the mail merge through Word for the same task takes the same amount of time, hence the presence of Publisher does not add to the time.*

Answer (score 1):

1. No, unfortunately, there isn't a way to do that. I've researched
   this myself quite a bit. The reason it does this is associated with
   caching.
2. You can use the **Select Recipients** option and choose **Select from Outlook Contacts**. Then select the distribution list(s). You can create as many distribution lists as you want and select them in waves. But I don't believe this will increase the speed at which the email messages are sent. To directly answer your question: Mail Merge *can* be done with distribution lists, but it will not increase the efficiency.
3. Again, unfortunately, no. The way the software has been made, only allows for a maximum recipient list of 7. I believe newer versions of the software (2010, 2013) offer the same amount, but possibly more.

I've had in the past a lot of different [mass mail](http://mailchimp.com/) distribution challenges. In the end, my solution ended up being either using a Mass Mail program, or sending them from outlook [and I learned HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/), (Hyper Text Markup Language), eliminating the need to use Publisher to send out content.

Hope this helps.

Comment: With respect to point no.2, there is no option to select distribution list, only contacts can be selected.